# How to HitTestObject with Multiple Objects of Same Class?

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, flash-cs6, flashdevelop, displayobject

Okay I can't seem to figure this out. I am new to displayObjectContainer and from what I have read I think I might need to access that in order to check for HitTestObject.

So I have a class called `mcCar` and another class called `mcMainScreen` which I gave a name of "mainScreen" through my main engine class like so  `private var mainScreen:mcMainScreen;` I am using Flash Develop for all the coding. Now in the class `mcMainScreen` I add a Movie clip object to it that I just named "bushes" But I add a lot of them to that `mcMainScreen` class on Flash CS6 just the visuals no code or anything. Now Usually I would just give the bushes an instance name and say:

```
if (mainScreen.bushes.hitTestObject(car))
{
   trace("HIT");
}
```

but since there are multiple instaces of "bushes" added on to the stage of my `mcMainScreen` Movie clip it only traces the hitTest with one of the bushes and not all of them. So I know I need to add them to an array and use a for loop to loop through all the "bushes" but I am having a lot of trouble doing so correctly. Is there a way that I don't have to give them instance names and can just loop through them all for the hitTes?

Any help would be appreciated thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to add the bushes to a array.

```
var bushArr:Array = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<mainScreen.numChildren; i++){
  var bush = getChildAt(i) as Bush;
  bushArr.push(bush);

}
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop);
function onLoop(evt:Event){

   for(var j=0;j<bushArr.length;J++){

      var bush:Bush = bushArr[j] as Bush;

      if (bush.hitTestObject(car))
      {
         trace("HIT");
      }

   }
}
```

The logic is, you need to create the bush and store it in an array. And in a lop you will check each one from the array with the car instance.

Comment: So I would need to make a class for the bush? Even though the bushes are added to the mcMainScreen Movie Clip?

Comment: is there any class associated with bush?

Comment: yeah the mcMainScreen Class. I add all the bushes on that Movie Clips visuals.

Comment: no i asked about bush. Is there any class associated with bush?

Comment: Should I make it, its own class?

Comment: That will be better . Make a class. Are you placing bushes in mcMainScreen through programatically or by ide?

Comment: I'm placing them by IDE. Just drag them from Flash CS6 Library onto the mainScreen Stage Area.

Comment: I have edited the code so that it could work with it. make a class for bush so it could identify the objects.

Comment: You should use a Vector instead of an Array.  You also will probably want to check for null before adding it to the Array/Vector, as you likely have other children on the mainScreen than just the bushes.

Comment: Thank you everyone this worked perfect was finally able to implement it I appreciate all your time!